# Nativescript Angular TabStrip Visibility set to collapse still take up space

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a navigation tab written as below. I wish to hide the tabStrip and setting the visibility to collapse did the job. However the hidden tabStrip still taken up white space in the area. Any ideas how i can get rid of the white space completely?

```
<Tabs selectedIndex="0" tabsPosition="top" >

    <TabStrip [visibility]="hideTab() ? 'visible' : 'collapse'">
        <TabStripItem class="special">
            <Label text="test"></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem>
    </TabContentItem>
</Tabs>
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: You are hiding the tab, not the tab bar. I doubt the component supports that. You may have to hide it natively, on iOS call `yourComponentInstance.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true`.

Comment: I tried this, but white space still present in the view

Comment: Please share a Playground sample.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=oLdbvO   - For IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide the TabBar on iOS, you will have adjust the frame size once the content is loaded.

```
onTabViewLoaded(tabView) {
    const viewController = tabView.viewController,
        tabBar = viewController.tabBar;

    tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(tabBar.frame.origin.x, tabBar.frame.origin.y, tabBar.frame.size.width, 0);
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=oLdbvO&v=7)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I tried it on playground and the tab bar is still there. 

Screenshot - https://imgur.com/eL3fJO2

Comment: It worked on the first go, looks like it had issues with event cycle. Using layoutChanged instead of loaded event seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me alot. Appreciated

Comment: One more question, the solution is the same if we have multiple tabstripitem and tabcontent right?

Comment: Yes, it should be. The framework internally sets frame size whenever the content is updated, layout change event helps you override that every time.

Comment: Share the updated playground sample, I can take a look.